# Why doesn't custom block appear on product page

Tags: module, layout, blocks, magento-1.14

Good afternoon, I'm suspecting this is an easy oversight.. I've been working today on putting a custom block onto a product page. But, nothing from my template is showing up. Take a look at my code below:

my config.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Foo_Bar>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Foo_Bar>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <foo_bar>
                <class>Foo_Bar_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>bar_resource</resourceModel>
            </foo_bar>
            <bar_resource>
                <class>CWD_Appratings_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <rating>bar_rating</rating>
                </entities>
            </bar_resource>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <foo_bar>Foo_Bar_Block</foo_bar>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <foo_bar>
                <class>Foo_Bar_Helper</class>
            </foo_bar>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <foo_bar>
                <file>foo_bar.xml</file>
            </foo_bar>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

My theme/default/layout/foo_bar.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view"  name="bar_widget" as="bar_widget" template="foo/bar/widget.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

and my code in theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
<div class="app-ratings">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bar_widget'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You wrote :
<blocks>
            < **foo_bar** >Foo_Bar_Block</ **cwd_appratings** >
</blocks>
But you have badly closed your node..

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I missed that closing tag while sanitizing my work-owned code before posting. In this posting, Foo is the company name, and Bar is the module name

Comment: You didn't get any error in your log files ?

Comment: Checked my error logs, and no logs given. On the DOM, I see  `<div class="app-ratings"></div>` then the rest of the page renders normally as though getChildHtml isn't returning anything

Comment: May be you need to put the node "<updates>" between  <frontend><layout> and <foo_bar><file> ?

Comment: That was it! I was missing the <updates> node! If you put it as an answer, I'll mark it!

Comment: Glad to have helped you ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a node in your config file :

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates> <-- this one
           <foo_bar>
               <file>foo_bar.xml</file>
           </foo_bar>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please add  update tag inside layout node in you config.xml like  `<updates>  <foo_bar> <file>foo_bar.xml</file> </foo_bar> </updates>`